# Random object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write script that will show random question. I can't figure out how to do that.

This is my NOT WORKING ( = doesn't write anything on the element) code:

```
function theQ(quest, ans) { // question constructor
  this.question = quest;
  this.answer = ans;
}
var quest1 = new theQ("1+1", "2"); // object 1
var quest2 = new theQ("2+2", "4"); // object 2
var container = document.getElementById("rendomQuestion"); // display
var randomNumber = Math.random(); // randomize 
var numQuestion = Math.floor(randomNumber * theQ.length); // between theQ number of objects
container.innerHTML += quest+numQuestion.question; // write the chosen question.
```

Please tell me what am i doing wrong here..

Edit - this is my HTML:

```
<p id="rendomQuestion"></p>
```

Comment: Please define "not working"? What errors do you get? Post your HTML as well. We need a [mcve]

Comment: That's a terrible duplicate there (it was http://stackoverflow.com/q/5117127/251311). Sorry community, but removing it, since it is entirely not relevant

Comment: @epascarello unless it's not what OP wants. OP does not need variable variables, but a help in choosing one value between the two.

Comment: Yep, and they do it because they don't know how to do it properly.

Comment: @epascarello top 5 answers there are irrelevant. I'm not sure a good duplicate would be something that requires you to check the least popular answer. Seriously, do you really think spreading `document.write(eval(name));` is a good way to "choose one random value of two"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an array (of two questions):

```js
function theQ(quest, ans) { // question constructor
  this.question = quest;
  this.answer = ans;
}
// *** Make it an array:
var quests = [new theQ("1+1", "2"),
              new theQ("2+2", "4")];
var container = document.getElementById("rendomQuestion");
var randomNumber = Math.random();
var numQuestion = Math.floor(randomNumber * theQ.length);
// *** Now use array notation:
container.textContent = quests[numQuestion].question;
```

```html
<p id="rendomQuestion"></p>
```

Comment: work like a charm. i try to use object in order to check if the user answer correct. thank you.

Comment: @trincot if you can have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43086730/create-random-arrays-in-javascript